# GWT Javascript Injection and JSNI

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni, stripe-payments

How can I use a Javascript library (downloaded from a CDN) inside JSNI code?

For example, I would like to call the javascript Stripe method, from within this JSNI method:

```
    private native void contactStripe(String creditCard, String cvc, String expiryMonth, String expiryYear) /*-{
        $wnd.Stripe.setPublishableKey('my_stripe_publishable_key');
        $wnd.Stripe.createToken({
            number: creditCard,
            cvc: cvc,
            exp_month: expiryMonth,
            exp_year: expiryYear
        }, callBack);
    }-*/;
```

... but the Stripe javascript method is undefined.

(more on the Stripe.createToken method https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms#create-a-single-use-token)

The Stripe javascript file is injected using the CDN url:

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("https://js.stripe.com/v1/").setCallback(
    new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
    public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
    }
    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
        contactStripe("0000111122223333", "456", "04", "2014");
    }
}).inject();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the JS script to be injected in a way that the global variables it defines are accessible through `$wnd`, you have to [`setWindow`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.FromUrl.html#setWindow%28com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject%29)`(`[`ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html#TOP_WINDOW)`)`.

Comment: I tried your solution, and the script is injected. When I call $wnd.console.log($wnd.Stripe.createToken), the whole function's code is logged, so I believe the script is well injected. However, I have trouble calling the $wnd.Stripe.createToken method :S

Comment: What is `callBack` in your code? (second argument to `createToken`) Hint: whatever it is, wrap it in $entry() when passing it to `createToken` (search for `$entry` in the JSNI doc)

Comment: callback is a Javascript function that accepts 2 arguments: callBack = function(status, response){//...}

Comment: Got it! I forgot to set m Stripe public key before calling the API: $wnd.Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_iYKWiY5SCfpcnxfyxYS0MSqz');. Your fix was necessary too, without the setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW) call, I'd get a com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to:

```
private native void contactStripe(String creditCard, String cvc, String expiryMonth, String expiryYear) /*-{

    console.log($wnd.Stripe);             // Should log 'Object'
    console.log($wnd.Stripe.createToken); // should log function
    var obj = {
        number: creditCard,
        cvc: cvc,
        exp_month: expiryMonth,
        exp_year: expiryYear
    };
    consloe.log(obj);                     // Should be 'Object'
    $wnd.Stripe.createToken(obj, callBack);
}-*/;
```

If you use the chrome debugging tools, you can inspect all these objects .

**update**
You don't provide the callback. Is that your problem?

Comment: console.log($wnd.Stripe.createToken); logs function (t,n,r){var i,s,o;n==null&&(n={});if(!t)throw"card required";if(typeof t!="object")throw"card invalid";typeof n=="function"?(r=n,n={}):typeof n!="object"&&(i=parseInt(n,10),n={},i>0&&(n.amount=i));for(s in t)o=t[s],delete t[s],t[e.underscore(s)]=o;return n.card=t,n.key||(n.key=e.key||e.publishableKey),e.validateKey(n.key),e.ajaxJSONP({url:""+e.endpoint+"/tokens",data:n,method:"POST",success:function(e,t){return typeof r=="function"?r(t,e):void 0},complete:e.complete(r),timeout:4e4})}

Comment: consloe.log(obj); logs Object {number: "0000111122223333", cvc: "456", exp_month: "04", exp_year: "2014"}

Comment: I tried this code: `stripeCallback = function(status, response){

            console.log(status);
            console.log(response);
        }

        console.log($wnd.Stripe);             // Should log 'Object'
        console.log($wnd.Stripe.createToken); // should log function

        var obj = {
            number: "2013",
            cvc: 2,
            exp_month: 3,
            exp_year: "lol"
        };

        console.log(obj);                     // Should be 'Object'

        $wnd.Stripe.createToken(obj, stripeCallback);`

But It doesn't work